# Use checkboxGroupInput in Shiny to make selectable plots from one tibble with plot_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, cowplot

I'm trying to make a Shiny app which will take an uploaded CSV file and convert it into a tibble and then make a series of plots with the same X but using different columns for Y data, one per plot. I want the user to be able to use check boxes to select which plots they want to display and plot the result using plot_grid.

So far I managed to get the script to render the plots the way I want them and to draw them all on the fly from plot_grid if I name them manually. I'm having trouble including checkboxGroupInput output as an input for plot_grid, the characted vector returned cannot be used as a grob object. Here's the relevant code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Title"),
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
                 #Select which plots will be displayed
                 checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "whichPlot",
                                    label = "Select data to plot",
                                    choices = c("Temperature" = "tempChart()",
                                                "Pressure" = "pressureChart()",
                                                "Dissolved Oxygen" = "airsat()",
                                                "pH" = "phChart()",
                                                "Air flow" = "airChart()",
                                                "Oxygen flow" = "O2Chart()"),
                                   selected = "Temperature"),
                 #Select time scale
                 selectInput("timeScale",
                              "Choose time scale to plot",
                              choices = c("Minutes",
                                          "Hours",
                                          "Days"),
                             selected = "Minutes"),
                 #Apply button to make graphs
                 actionButton("DoIt", "Plot data"),
                 br(),
                
    ),
                
    mainPanel( 
              plotOutput("plot"),
#the outputs below are not necessary, I just use them to see if I'm going in the right direction
              textOutput("tableTitle"),
              tableOutput("table"),
              textOutput("selection"),
              tableOutput("dataSummary")
              
              
              ) 
    )
)   

server <- function(input, output) {

    #A dummy tibble that I use for testing. will be replaced by Load button
   dataDF <- tibble(date = c("01/01/2021","01/01/2021","01/01/2021","01/01/2021"), time = c("10:51:02","10:52:02","10:53:02","10:54:02"),
                temp = c(20.000,22.000,23.000,24.000), pressure = c(50.000,50.000,50.000,50.000),
                pH = c(7.000, 7.230, 7.100, 7.040), pO2 = c(100.000, 90.000, 80.000, 70.000),
                airflow = c(1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000), O2flow = c(1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000), user = c("user","user","user","user"),
                level = c(3,3,3,3), acid = c("00:00:00","00:00:00","00:00:00","00:00:00"), base =c("00:00:00","00:00:00","00:00:00","00:00:00"),
                mins = c(0,2,3,4), hrs = c(0,60,180,360), dys = c(0,15,25,35))
   output$table <- renderTable(head(dataDF))

   #This changes the X axis scale and works well
        colsel <- reactive({
    switch(input$timeScale,
                      "Minutes" = 13,
                      "Hours" = 14,
                      "Days" = 15)
        })
           dataT <- reactive({
              df <-dataDF[, 3:8]
              df$runTime = pull(dataDF, colsel())
              df
           })


     #A control table output to make sure tibble transformation worked (it works!)
output$dataSummary <- renderTable({
                    head(dataT())})

     #Create a list of plots to be drawn from the checkboxes
plots <- reactive({
        paste(input$whichPlot, sep = ",")
     })

#save all the plots to individual objects to be chosen from later
  
     airChart <- reactive({
        ggplot(dataT(), aes(x = runTime, y = airflow))+
             geom_line(size = 1, color = "#00B388")+
             labs(x = paste("Runtime in",input$timeScale), y = "Air flow [L/min]")+
             scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_extended(n = 10))+
             ylim(0, 1)
     })

     tempChart <- reactive({
        ggplot (dataT(), aes(runTime, temp))+
             geom_line(size = 1, color = "#00B388")+
             labs(x = paste("Runtime in",input$timeScale), y = expression(paste("Temperature [", degree, "C]")))+
             scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_extended(n = 10))+
             ylim(15, 45)
     })

     airsat <- reactive({
        ggplot(dataT(), aes(runTime, pO2))+
             geom_line(size = 1, color = "#00B388")+
             labs(x = paste("Runtime in",input$timeScale), y = "%O2 saturation")+
             scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_extended(n = 10))+
             ylim(80, 100)
     })


     phChart <- reactive({
        ggplot(dataT(), aes(runTime, pH))+
             geom_line(size = 1, color = "#00B388")+
             labs(x = paste("Runtime in",input$timeScale), y = "pH")+
             scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_extended(n = 10))+
             ylim(1,15)
     })


     O2Chart <- reactive({
        ggplot(dataT(), aes(runTime, O2flow))+
             geom_line(size = 1, color = "#00B388")+
             labs(x = paste("Runtime in",input$timeScale), y = "O2 flow [L/min]")+
             scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_extended(n = 10))+
             ylim(0,10)
     })


     pressureChart <- reactive({
        ggplot(dataT(), aes(runTime, pressure))+
             geom_line(size = 1, color = "#00B388")+
             labs(x = paste("Runtime in",input$timeScale), y = "Pressure [mbar]")+
             scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_extended(n = 10))+
             ylim(0,220)
     })

#Plot my charts
observeEvent(input$DoIt,{
       output$plot <- renderPlot({
               (plot_grid(plots(), ncol = 2, labels = "auto"))
})

})  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I try to use it, I get an error

> Warning in as_grob.default(plot) :
> Cannot convert object of class character into a grob.
> Warning in grid.echo.recordedplot(dl, newpage, prefix) :
> No graphics to replay

If I replace the last line with

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
               (plot_grid(tempChart(), airsat(), O2Chart(), pressureChart(), ncol = 2, labels = "auto"))
```

it works just fine. I'm not sure if there's a way to bypass the character to grob issue or if I'm making it unnecessarily too difficult. I looked at other solutions with if (which I don't fully understand) but I don't think they'll help here. It's my first contact with Shiny, so don't be too harsh please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a different strategy here. Instead of storing every plot separately in a `reactive`, you can store them all in one list. Here I used a `reactiveValues` object that gets updated via an `observeEvent`. (In principal, you could even use a simple list to store the plots, because in your case the reactivity comes from the `observeEvent`. Using `reactiveValues` allows you to use single plots outside the cowplot with reactivity.)

Then you can use `input$whichPlot` just to index the list of plots. Also, putting an `output$plot <- renderPlot` inside an `observeEvent` isn't usually considered good practice, because `renderPlot` itself already has reactivity.

In order to only update the plot when `input$DoIt` is pressed, I use the `bindEvent` from the brand new `shiny 1.6.0`.

```
library(shiny)
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      #Select which plots will be displayed
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "whichPlot",
                         label = "Select data to plot",
                         choices = c("Temperature" = "temperature",
                                     "Pressure" = "pressure",
                                     "Dissolved Oxygen" = "dissolved_oxygen",
                                     "pH" = "ph",
                                     "Air flow" = "air_flow",
                                     "Oxygen flow" = "oxygen_flow"),
                         selected = "Temperature"),
      #Select time scale
      selectInput("timeScale",
                  "Choose time scale to plot",
                  choices = c("Minutes",
                              "Hours",
                              "Days"),
                  selected = "Minutes"),
      #Apply button to make graphs
      actionButton("DoIt", "Plot data"),
      br(),
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel( 
      plotOutput("plot"),
      #the outputs below are not necessary, I just use them to see if I'm going in the right direction
      textOutput("tableTitle"),
      tableOutput("table"),
      textOutput("selection"),
      tableOutput("dataSummary")
      
      
    ) 
  )
)   

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #A dummy tibble that I use for testing. will be replaced by Load button
  dataDF <- tibble(date = c("01/01/2021","01/01/2021","01/01/2021","01/01/2021"), time = c("10:51:02","10:52:02","10:53:02","10:54:02"),
                   temp = c(20.000,22.000,23.000,24.000), pressure = c(50.000,50.000,50.000,50.000),
                   pH = c(7.000, 7.230, 7.100, 7.040), pO2 = c(100.000, 90.000, 80.000, 70.000),
                   airflow = c(1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000), O2flow = c(1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000), user = c("user","user","user","user"),
                   level = c(3,3,3,3), acid = c("00:00:00","00:00:00","00:00:00","00:00:00"), base =c("00:00:00","00:00:00","00:00:00","00:00:00"),
                   mins = c(0,2,3,4), hrs = c(0,60,180,360), dys = c(0,15,25,35))
  output$table <- renderTable(head(dataDF))
  
  #This changes the X axis scale and works well
  colsel <- reactive({
    switch(input$timeScale,
           "Minutes" = 13,
           "Hours" = 14,
           "Days" = 15)
  })
  dataT <- reactive({
    df <-dataDF[, 3:8]
    df$runTime = pull(dataDF, colsel())
    df
  })
  
  
  #A control table output to make sure tibble transformation worked (it works!)
  output$dataSummary <- renderTable({
    head(dataT())})
  
  # initialise reactiveValues object
  plots <- reactiveValues(
    temperature = NULL,
    pressure = NULL,
    dissolved_oxygen = NULL,
    ph = NULL,
    air_flow = NULL,
    oxygen_flow = NULL
  )
  
  # the plots only change when dataT or input$timeScale changes
  observeEvent(c(dataT(), input$timeScale), {
    plots$temperature <- ggplot (dataT(), aes(runTime, temp))+
      geom_line(size = 1, color = "#00B388")+
      labs(x = paste("Runtime in",input$timeScale), y = expression(paste("Temperature [", degree, "C]")))+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_extended(n = 10))+
      ylim(15, 45)
    
    plots$pressure <- ggplot(dataT(), aes(runTime, pressure))+
      geom_line(size = 1, color = "#00B388")+
      labs(x = paste("Runtime in",input$timeScale), y = "Pressure [mbar]")+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_extended(n = 10))+
      ylim(0,220)
    
    plots$dissolved_oxygen <- ggplot(dataT(), aes(runTime, pO2))+
      geom_line(size = 1, color = "#00B388")+
      labs(x = paste("Runtime in",input$timeScale), y = "%O2 saturation")+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_extended(n = 10))+
      ylim(80, 100)
    
    plots$ph <- ggplot(dataT(), aes(runTime, pH))+
      geom_line(size = 1, color = "#00B388")+
      labs(x = paste("Runtime in",input$timeScale), y = "pH")+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_extended(n = 10))+
      ylim(1,15)
    
    plots$air_flow <- ggplot(dataT(), aes(x = runTime, y = airflow))+
      geom_line(size = 1, color = "#00B388")+
      labs(x = paste("Runtime in",input$timeScale), y = "Air flow [L/min]")+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_extended(n = 10))+
      ylim(0, 1)
    
    plots$oxygen_flow <- ggplot(dataT(), aes(runTime, O2flow))+
      geom_line(size = 1, color = "#00B388")+
      labs(x = paste("Runtime in",input$timeScale), y = "O2 flow [L/min]")+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_extended(n = 10))+
      ylim(0,10)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    premade_plots <- reactiveValuesToList(plots)
    do.call("plot_grid", c(premade_plots[input$whichPlot],
            ncol = 2, labels = "auto"))
  }) %>% 
    bindEvent(input$DoIt) 
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This worked so well, thank you! I have so much more to learn...
Next challange: make the load button work and save a table and then use a slider to choose an X axis frame. Wish me luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("grp", "Select", choices = NULL),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  tibble(x = 1:10,
         y1 = sample(1:10),
         y2 = sample(1:10),
         y3 = sample(1:10),
         y4 = sample(1:10))  %>% 
    pivot_longer(-x) -> df

  observe({
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "grp", "Select",
                             choices = unique(df$name),
                             selected = unique(df$name)[1])
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    df %>% 
      filter(name == req(input$grp)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x, value)) +
      geom_col() +
      facet_wrap(~name, ncol = 1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I see what you want me to do. Not sure if faceting is going to give me the graphical output I want, but I'm trying to make it work. I adapted that example to my tables, but I'm getting an error with filter:

`Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive', 'function')"
  168: %>%
  167: renderPlot [D:\Documents\R\playground\StockVis/app.R#72]
  165: func
  125: drawPlot
  111: <reactive:plotObj>
   95: drawReactive
   82: origRenderFunc
   81: output$plot
    1: runApp
`